# How to fix "Unable to activate Windows Tailored application" on Win8

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I get "Unable to activate Windows Tailored application" error in Metro app when I'm running it under debugger of Visual Studio 11. I installed Windows 8 x64 Developer Preview on my Dell E6510 laptop.

I googled it and found out many people saying it happens when screen resolution is smaller than 800x600 but it's 1920x1280 in my case.

The app itself contains nothing. It's just empty wizard created application which is nothing but windows with black background.

Any ideas? It seems like very common issue.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to solve the problem. All you're going to get are a bunch of people posting suggestions without a definitive answer, and that's not really a good fit to a Q&A site. I suggest undertaking a few more debugging steps yourself. Can you create a new, blank project in VS 11 and run that? What's the exact output in the "Output" window? Can you run the application *outside* of VS 11's debugger?

Comment: Also, it's not "Visual Studio 2011", it's only a coincidence that VS 10 was released in 2010, and VS 11 definitely wasn't released in 2011 considering it's 2012 now. The code name is just Visual Studio 11.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that but considering massive amount of people who experienced the same issue I hope somebody sorted it out. Non-Metro projects work fine. I'm debugging my production 15-projects solution in it right now. I'm gonna test Metro app outside of VS now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite bizarre but I figured it out.

**It turns out not a single Metro application works under Administrator account including my apps. I'm talking about built-in Administrator account that is disabled by default (but which I enabled).**

It gives "Access denied" error so I suspect it's somehow related to the way WinRT COM objects were registered or something like that. Go figure.

I hope somebody from Microsoft is reading this.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to wait 2 weeks for the next release.  The developer preview is full of fun bugs like this.  I've seen this error caused by invalid app.xaml.  Double check that you really haven't changed anything.  I've also seen this error sometimes resolved by rebooting.  Have fun!